# How to wait for a Process pool to have a free worker

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have some heavy tasks which I'm submitting to a ProcessPoolExecutor. The problem is that as the executor holds the pending tasks It's consuming too much memory. I'd like to wait in case that the executor is full, blocking the main thread until a worker is free, so I could have a fixed number of parallel tasks without accumulate pending heavy tasks:

```py
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor


def f(arg):
    print(f'Arg -> {arg}')
    # Heavy stuff


executor = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3)
for i in range(20):
    if executor.wait_some_free_worker():  # THIS is what I need
        executor.submit(f, i)

executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

I the example above **I'd have only 3 task being executed in parallel** and only when there would be a free worker It'd continue with the next loop.

Thanks in advace and sorry about my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `concurrent.futures.wait` to wait for completion of futures, and submit new ones whenever there are not enough outstanding futures:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor , wait, FIRST_COMPLETED

def f(arg):
    print(f'Arg -> {arg}')

max_concurrent = 3  # how many futures to use at most
pending = set()     # currently running futures

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=3) as executor:
    for i in range(20):
        # wait until there are less-than-desired active futures
        while len(pending) >= max_concurrent:
            done, pending = wait(pending, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
        pending.add(executor.submit(f, i))
```

This can be factored out into a re-usable helper function:

```
from concurrent.futures import Executor, wait, FIRST_COMPLETED, ALL_COMPLETED

def map_lazy(executor: Executor, func, *iterables, max_pending=10):
    pending = set()
    for args in zip(*iterables):
        while len(pending) >= max_pending:
            _, pending = wait(pending, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
        pending.add(executor.submit(func, *args))
    wait(pending, return_when=ALL_COMPLETED)
```

Comment: Hi! First of all thank you so much for your answer. I'd like to know why you put a `while` instead of an `if` to check if number of pending task is mora than the limit? It's due to a race condition?

Comment: @Genarito Using a ``while`` instead of an ``if`` for such balancing algorithms makes them easier to adjust, e.g. for a variable-number of pending tasks.